# Error in android code

Tags: java, android

i'm in need of some help here.....i'm planning to create a flames app in android ...i got messed up with the coding. can any one help me.I'm trying to print the number of letters which are not in common. This is the coding.i need to find some way to find the number of common chars.

```
`package com.rajzflames;

//import com.kct.health_maintainer.Chk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0, k;
String p;
Editable st1;
Editable st2;
// final int i=0;
// final int j=0;
// String,p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

    st1 = e1.getText();
    st2 = e2.getText();

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            while (i < st1.length()) 
            {
                while (j < st2.length()) 
                {
                    if (st1.charAt(i) == st2.charAt(j)) 
                    {
                        st1.delete(i, i);
                        st2.delete(j, j);
                        i++;
                        // j++;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            k = st1.length() + st2.length();
            p = Integer.toString(k);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, p, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: this is too much code. also the title is not very good

Comment: i really don't get what you are trying to do. what do flame have in common with numbers and letters

Comment: What is the error? What exactly is your question? Please format (indent) your code properly, that makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Your question is not clear, and you are asking for algorithm help (I think) which is generally hard (and requires good clear questions).

Comment: well it's actually an Indian game.in which a we'd find hw a boy will b related to a girl.(F)riends. (L)over (A)ffection (M)arriage (E)nemy (S)s** partner. and this is the first time i'm posting a question . sorry for the inconvenience guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the number of common characters by the following method. I have changed `p` to `int`

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ArrayList<Character> charArray1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> charArray2 = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (char character : st1.toString().toCharArray())
        {
            charArray1.add(character);
        }

        for (char character : st2.toString().toCharArray())
        {
            charArray2.add(character);
        }

        for (Character character : charArray2)
        {
            if (charArray1.contains(character))
                p++;
        }

        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "" + p, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

});
```

Comment: Thnx alot dude...it wrkd.... :)